# How can I highlight diff output text in restructuredtext in sphinx?

Tags: diff, highlight, restructuredtext

I tried to find but failed.

I think coloring of lines that start with '+' in red

... and coloring of lines that start with '-' in blue

... would be enough.

```
hello.c::

    +#else                                 <<<<< want this line in red
     ISR_RESULT ISRs(U32 Interrupt, U32 Vector)
    +#endif                                <<<<< want this line in red
     {
    -//     printf ("Get IRQs \r\n");      <<<<< want this line in blue
    -       switch (Interrupt)             <<<<< want this line in blue
    -       {                              <<<<< want this line in blue
    -         case ISR_MBOX0:              <<<<< want this line in blue
```

Comment: Please include a code sample. See also the list of [diff lexers for pygments](https://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-diff-patch-formats) which are used as languages by Sphinx.

Comment: I rewrote with code sample as Steve recommended. But the documents Steve pointed didn't help me. I couldn't find any hint from there...

Comment: First [demo the code that you want to diff](https://pygments.org/demo/#try). Does your local test look like the demo? If it does, then to change the style of the default highlighting, you need to apply a custom style in your theme's CSS file.

Comment: Thank you Steve! But, it's not that simple for me.... But thank you for providing demo service url.

Comment: @Jeonghum How does your `*.rst` file actually look like?

Comment: @sinoroc I edited my original question above. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably should use the [`code-block` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block) and use [*Pygment*'s `diff` lexer](https://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-diff-patch-formats). Your `*.rst` file should probably look like this:

```
.. code-block:: diff

    +#else
     ISR_RESULT ISRs(U32 Interrupt, U32 Vector)
    +#endif
     {
    -//     printf ("Get IRQs \r\n");
    -       switch (Interrupt)
    -       {
    -         case ISR_MBOX0:
```

Comment: I missed to say thank you! This is a 100% perfect answer!